# After getting the data from ajax POST method open another window in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, python-3.x

I want to pass data in views and open another html file in window.open("{% url 'view_detail' %}", "_self"), when i use ajax it post data successfully in views, Now i have to open this url, when i use this syntax window.open("{% url 'view_detail' %}", "_self"), it goes to same function and return nothing, How should i avoid this, .js file

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        console.log("======")
        $('#NextButton').on('click', function ()
     {
     console.log('After Clicking Next Buttton')
     $.ajax({
        url : "/analytics/show_analytics/",
        type : "POST",
        async: true,
        data : {
            industry: $("input[name='analyticsindustry']:checked").val(),
            domain: $("input[class='analyticsdomain']:checked").val(),
            functions: $("input[class='analyticsfunctions']:checked").val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    },
        success : function(data) {
            var c = document.getElementById('domaincheckbox2').value;
            alert(data)
            window.open("{% url 'show_analytics', '_self' %)}")
            show_a(data)

            }
         })
        return false;
        })
    } 
</script>
```

views.py

```
def show_analytics(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    #posts = analyticsreport.objects.values('Domain', 'Analytics').distinct()
    #print('POSTS', posts)
    total_analytics = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        industry = request.POST.get('industry')
        domain = request.POST.get('domain')
        functions = request.POST.get('functions')
        print("Industry", industry)
        print("Domain", domain)
        print("Functions", functions)
        #total_analytics = []
        query = ('select id, Analytics from analytics_analyticsreport where Industry = ' + "'" + industry + "'")
        result = analyticsreport.objects.raw(query)
        print(len(result))
        print(result)
        for i in range(len(result)):
            analytics = result[i].Analytics
            print('Analytics', analytics)
            if analytics not in total_analytics:
                total_analytics.append(analytics)
    print('Total_Analytics', total_analytics)
    return render_to_response('analytics/demo.html', {'posts': total_analytics})
```

html file which i want to display

```
{% extends 'analytics/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <!-- New Chart Comes Here --->
                    <div class="card card-stats">
                        <div class="card-body ">
                            <div class="card-header ">
                            <!--div class="progress-container progress-info"-->
                                <h6 class="card -title" style="color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#008B8B;" align="center"> Choose Analytics </h6>
                                {% for post in posts %}
                                <p>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1"  name = "analytics"  value= {{post}} style="margin-left:10px;"> {{post}}
                                </p>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-16 col-md-16 col-sm-20" style="float:right;">

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-16 col-md-16 col-sm-20" style="float:right;">
                        <button type="button" id="button_for_previous" class="myPreviousFunction"> Previous </button>
                        <button type="button" id="button_for_proceed1" class="myNextFunction1"> Proceed For Next</button>
                    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: if your javascript is in a separate .js file, then `{% url 'show_analytics', '_self' %)}` isn't part of a django template and the template tag `{% url %}` will never get executed by Django. Check in your browser developer tools so see if the URL is displayed correctly in the source file.

Comment: Note that this is also the case for `{{ csrf_token }}` which if included in a separate .js file won't do anything.

Comment: Yup it is not in .js file this is in html file

Comment: html file contains so many lines that's why i put only javascript code

Comment: So if you look at the source html file in your browser, what's the line `window.open(...)` showing?

Comment: `{% url 'show_analytics', '_self' %)}` is wrong anyway, the "_self" should be outside of the template tag.

Comment: It open the demo.html file which is in views.py and and pass total_analytics=[]

Comment: I mean look at the source code of your html page in your browser (not in your editor), to see what Django made of {% url %}. The actual javascript that the browser is executing.

Comment: if i use without "_self" it show pop-up blocked message

Comment: `window.open("{% url 'show_analytics' %}", "_self")` is correct (what you wrote in your question), the code in your example is not correct. But please show us the actual javascript code as the browser sees it, not the django template code.

Comment: me actual problem is first it call via ajax post method in function(data) it it goes to show_analytics in views.py after success "window.open" again move to same function

Comment: so why are you using the `show_analytics` url in window.open() if you want to open another page?

Comment: after getting the data from ajax can i open "demo.html" with  different method i have to also pass the posts data in "demo.html" ?

Comment: Note that if you do a GET request on `show_analytics` it will just render 'analytics/demo.html' with posts = [] because total_analytics = []

Comment: i had try with GET but it didn't return anything because next time when i call window.open("{% url 'show_analytics' %}", "_self") nothing in request.GET.get('industry')

Comment: window.open() just makes a GET request. So yes, you don't get anything back since total_analytics = []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186522/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-jay-pratap-pandey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax is posting some data to your `show_analytics` Django view. That view returns an HTML document with the data you want, but you're not doing anything with that. Instead you `window.open()` the `show_analytics` view (which submits a new request, GET this time), and return the HTML document without any data because you never get into the `if request.method == 'POST'` code.

Since you're not changing anything in the back-end (not saving to the database), you shouldn't have to use POST anyway. What you want is:

- Change your `show_analytics` view to only process a GET request and check for the `request.GET` parameters.
- Change your "next" button to be a regular link `<a href="{% url 'show_analytics' %}>`
- Change your javascript to append the chosen parameters to the href attribute of the link, so each time the user changes the input values, the link becomes something like `/show_analytics?analyticsdomain=something&analyticsindustry=myplace`:

```js
var baseURL = {% url 'show_analytics' %};  // at the beginning of your script, assuming it's inside your template
// then when user input changes
var newURL = baseURL + "?analyticsindustry=" + $("input[name='analyticsindustry']:checked").val();
```

Then when the user clicks the button, it's just like clicking on a regular link, which will do a GET request to your view.

And finally as a side note: your raw database query is dangerous and prone to SQL injection because you don't sanitise the input value. You just take the raw string that the user submitted and inject it into your query. This is very bad practice!

Comment: @dirkroten How can i pass list(array) data